# 2010 Ford Fusion with a 3.0L

Tags: ford, starting, fusion

I have a 2010 Ford Fusion with a 3.0L I turn the key all the dash lights come on and the radio comes on but it won't crank over but when I run a jump wire off the solenoid it will crank over and start I checked all the fuses and all the relays and they are all good I can't figure out what the problem is any suggestions.

Comment: Do you mean that you have manually added power to the small connector on the solenoid, so that the solenoid pulls in?

Comment: Do you have the wiring diagram for the vehicle?

Comment: Is there a factory theft deterrent system, blinking or flashing to indicate theft mode disabling the starting circuit? Some manufacturers disable the starting circuit while others disable injector or spark systems to prevent theft. If factory security isn't disabling the staring circuit then you may be attempting to diagnose either a blown fuse, faulty relay, or wiring problem,